# Replacing a string whose surroundings are known but the value of the string is not known Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, file-io

I have a string of the form

```
**var beforeDate = new Date('2015-08-21')**
```

Here i do not know the value between the paranthesis(). I want to replace this date with any other date. How can I do it in Python ?
I thought of opening the file and then using standard replace function of the language but since the value beween () is not known, that wont be possible.

There would be a lot of code this snippet as well as after this snippet so replacing the whole line with a new line would not work as it would overwrite the code that surrounds this snippet.

Comment: Is this something which appears only once in a file, or are there several occurrences? Is the same date used in more than one place?

Comment: Once it would be initialized in the variable beforeDate = new Date('date_I_want_to_Put') and then once its value would be used at a particular place for comparison , if some_date > beforeDate ....

Comment: Have you considered / dismissed using a regular expression (re module) to find the string to replace?

Comment: _"i do not know the value between the paranthesis()"_. Do you know anything about the structure of the value, even if you don't know the value itself? For instance, will it always be a string literal enclosed by single quote marks?

Comment: @James: Yes regular expressions seem to be the best choice to me too, dont know how to use them though

Comment: @Kevin: Yes it would be a literal string enclosed by single quote marks and it would always be a date of the form 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using regex? Example:

temp.txt

```
print "I've got a lovely bunch of coconuts"
var beforeDate = new Date('2015-08-21') #date determined by fair die roll
print "Here they are, standing in a row"
```

main.py

```
import re

new_value = "'1999-12-31'"
with open("temp.txt") as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    data = re.sub(r"(var beforeDate = new Date\().*?(\))", "\\1"+new_value+"\\2", data)
with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(data)
```

output.txt after running:

```
print "I've got a lovely bunch of coconuts"
var beforeDate = new Date('1999-12-31') #date determined by fair die roll
print "Here they are, standing in a row"
```

Comment: Why did you indent the line with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:, wouldnt it be in the same indentation level as the previous with ?

Comment: Good eye. the second `with` indeed does not need to be indented inside the first. Edited.

Comment: " Although it runs good on the sample code you have provided, on my code it doesnt work. A line which was \n    var afterDate = new Date('2015-08-19'); has been converted to \n    P15-08-13);

Comment: Just try with a change in your code
new_value =  "1999-12-31", I have just removed the single quotes in the new_value.

Comment: Interesting... Could you put an example document on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so I can replicate the problem on my own machine?

Comment: Try replacing your `\\1` and `\\2` with `\g<1>` and `\g<2>`. Your `new_value` starts with a digit.

Comment: You should leave the single quotes in `before` and `after`. Otherwise, the replacement strings will get confused about what groups you're trying to match because it doesn't know where "\1" ends and "2015" begins. It will think you're trying to match group 12015. Alternatively, if you really don't want the quote marks, you can make the replacement string be `"\\g<1>"+before+"\\g<2>"`, which is unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks both of you :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I usually find re.split() to be simpler to use than re.sub().  This reuses Kevin's code, and will capture everything that it does (plus the middle group) and then replace the middle group:

```
import re

new_value = "'1999-12-31'"
with open("temp.txt") as infile:
    data = infile.read()

data = re.split(r"(var beforeDate = new Date\()(.*?)(\))", data)
# data[0] is everything before the first capture
# data[1] is the first capture
# data[2] is the second capture -- the one we want to replace
data[2] = new_value

with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(''.join(stuff))
```

You could blow off capturing the middle group, but then you're inserting stuff in the list.  It's easier just to do a replace.

OTOH, this particular problem might be small enough not to require the re hammer.  Here is the same code without re:

```
new_value = "'1999-12-31'"
with open("temp.txt") as infile:
    data = infile.read()

data = list(data.partition('var beforeDate = new Date('))
data += data.pop().partition(')')
data[2] = new_value

with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for stuff in data:
        outfile.write(stuff)
```

Comment: Your approach is pretty ingenious :) +1 for that